# Where on Stack Exchange can I ask a question about lucid dreams?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about lucid dreams, but I don't know which Stack Exchange website I should post it on.

Comment: Do you have an actual question? Because [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24191/a-strange-experience-during-my-sleep) was pretty much just a story

Comment: Okey i'll write down my question

Answer (score 7):

As others have pointed out, [the question you asked on SciFi SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24191/a-strange-experience-during-my-sleep) was not appropriate for any Stack Exchange site.

In general, you might try Biology SE, Cognitive Sciences SE or Philosophy SE for questions about the biological basis for, effects of or meaning of lucid dreams.

If you have a question about lucid dreaming in another context, such as a lucid dream experienced by a video game character, you could look for an SE site for that domain (in this example, Arqade, AKA Gaming SE).

Comment: The sidebar has reminded me that there's also [a "Let's get philosophical" chatroom](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139) here on Meta Stack Overflow, but I can't say if your question will be taken seriously there.

Answer (score 5):

I think there is a Stack Exchange where scientists might ask and answer questions about dreams.

But [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24191/a-strange-experience-during-my-sleep) is not a question. It's just you telling us your dream. Stack Exchange is a questions and answers platform. Not a site to share dream narrations. I'm sure those exist somewhere on the Internet. Keep looking.

Comment: now it's a question about an experience I had in adream but I don't know is it a lucid dream or no

Comment: A lucid dream just means you were aware you were dreaming during the dream, so by definition - yes it was. None of the other details are important.